# Applying a function to multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

I want to apply a function to multiple columns. My data in the dataframe `data` is structured as follows:

```
col1 col2 col3
x    x    x
x    x    x
x    x    x
```

In particular, I want to apply an ADF test on the time-series of each column.

I thought something like this might work:

```
f <- function(x) ur.df(x, type = "none", lags = 10, selectlags = "AIC"))
sapply(data, f)
```

However, it seems that there's a problem handling the "variable" of the column.

How is it done correctly?

Update: Use this to create three columns with random values:

```
data = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(30), nrow=10))
```

Comment: What package is `ur.df()` from?

Comment: I believe it's from `urca`

Comment: Could you add some actual data and your expected output? What is ur.df and how exactly does your 'problem' look like; what goes wrong?

Comment: ur.df is a function from the urca package. I can't provide the data (unfortunately) but basically you can create random values for each column (152 observations)

Comment: `data <- Raotbl3[, 1:3]; sapply(data, f)` appears to work for me.  You have two `))` in your function `f`.  Might that be the issue?

Comment: Would apply work? eg. ``apply(data, 2, FUN = ur.df,type = "none", lags = 10, selectlags = "AIC")``

Comment: @holzben For me it works; just as `apply(data,2,f)`

Comment: "you can create random values for each column" - you have this completely backwards. YOU can create random variables for each column and put that in your question!

Comment: @jlhoward I just updated this

Comment: none of the proposed solutions worked yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code as far as I can see:

1) In your function definition, you have one parenthesis too much; it should be:

```
f <- function(x) ur.df(x, type = "none", lags = 10, selectlags = "AIC")
```

2) The number of lags is too high for the given dimension of the dataset. The following works (note the different dimensions and lags of and for the different datasets, respectively):

```
library(urca)
data <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(300), nrow=100))
f <- function(x) ur.df(x, type = "none", lags = 10, selectlags = "AIC")
sapply(data,f)

data2 = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(30), nrow=10))
f2 <- function(x) ur.df(x, type = "none", lags = 3, selectlags = "AIC")
sapply(data2,f2)
```

which gives you the following output (numbers can of course differ since I did not set a seed for `rnorm`):

> $X1 Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root / Cointegration Test The
>   value of the test statistic is: -6.0255
>
> $X2  Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root / Cointegration Test   The
>   value of the test statistic is: -7.164
>
> $X3 Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root / Cointegration Test  The
>   value of the test statistic is: -5.0921

and

> $X1 Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root / Cointegration Test The
>   value of the test statistic is: -1.2124
>
> $X2 Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root / Cointegration Test The
>   value of the test statistic is: -0.8715
>
> $X3 Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root / Cointegration Test  The
>   value of the test statistic is: -0.6598