# Applying univariate coxph function to multiple covariates (columns) at once

Tags: r, cox-regression

First, I gathered from this link [Applying a function to multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570988/applying-a-function-to-multiple-columns) that using the "function" function would perhaps do what I'm looking for.  However, I have not been able to make the leap from thinking about it in the way presented to making it actually work in my situation (or really even knowing where to start).  I'm a beginner in R so I apologize in advance if this is a really "newb" question.  My data is a data frame that consists of an event variable (tumor recurrence) and a time variable (followup time/time to recurrence) as well as recurrence risk factors (t-stage, tumor size,age at dx, etc.). Some risk factors are categorical and some are continuous. I have been running my univariate analysis by hand, one at a time like this example univariateageatdx<-coxph(survobj~agedx), and then collecting the data.  This gets very tedious for multiple factors and doing it for a few different recurrence types.  I figured there must be a way to code such that I could basically have one line of code that had the coxph equation and then applied it to all of my variables of interest and spit out a result that had the univariate analysis results for each factor. I tried using cbind to bind variables (i.e `x<-cbind("agedx","tumor size")` then running cox `coxph(recurrencesurvobj~x)` but this of course just did the multivariate analysis on these variables and didn't split them out as true univariate analyses.

I also tried the following code based on a similar problem that I found on a different site, but it gave the error shown and I don't know quite what to make of it.  Is this on the right track?

```
f <- as.formula(paste('regionalsurvobj ~', paste(colnames(nodcistradmasvssubcutmasR)[6-9], collapse='+')))
```

I then ran it has coxph(f) 
Gave me the results of a multivariate cox analysis.

Thanks! 
**edit: I just fixed the error, I needed to use the column numbers I suppose not the names.  Changes are reflected in the code above.  However, it still runs the variables selected as a multivariate analysis and not as the true univariate analysis...

Comment: It runs as a multivariable analysis because you added a '+' as collapse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to go the formula-route (which in your case with multiple outcomes and multiple variables might be the most practical way to go about it) you need to create a formula per model you want to fit. I've split the steps here a bit (making formulas, making models and extracting data), they can off course be combined this allows you to inspect all your models.

```
#example using transplant data from survival package
#make new event-variable: death  or no death
#to have dichot outcome
transplant$death <- transplant$event=="death"

#making formulas
univ_formulas <- sapply(c("age","sex","abo"),function(x)as.formula(paste('Surv(futime,death)~',x))
)
#making a list of models
univ_models <- lapply(univ_formulas, function(x){coxph(x,data=transplant)})

#extract data (here I've gone for HR and confint)
univ_results <- lapply(univ_models,function(x){return(exp(cbind(coef(x),confint(x))))})
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much, saved me hours haha.  Now I just need to digest how you did it and the coding behind it so I could reproduce it again.

Comment: Follow up question, how would I change it to be 95% confidence intervals and how would I get it to show the wald test p-value?

Comment: I already tried to split all the steps. If anything is unclear, please ask. About  your last question: try to extract your desired result from one model first and then extend that to a list of models.

Comment: Fair enough, it was clear I just need to read up more on designing functions and the notation so I can customize it to exactly what I need.  The process you posted worked perfectly I just needed the confidence interval extracted to be in the 95% interval format and needed the p-value as well as the coefficient but I'll figure it out.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Heroka Thanks for your input. I tried it and it is nice but would be great if you can edit your answer to show how to extract p value for each assssed variable and then how to export to csv file. Appreciate your input.

Comment: I tried this and I got p value. `univ_results <- lapply(univ_models,function(x){cbind(exp(cbind(coef(x),confint(x))),Pval=coef(summary(x))[5])});univ_results`

Comment: Please see this [link](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/cox-proportional-hazards-model)